# Using Volley Library Uploading image to the server is showing text file not a actual image

Tags: java, android, android-volley, image-uploading, multipart

Actually I worked with `volley library` `multipart` for uploading images to the server.
This task is perfectly done.

I am able to upload images to the server successfully but now the problem I am facing is that on the server `Image` is looking like a `textfile` it is not a actual image format...

I am struggling with this issue, can anyone help me or suggest me to resolve this issue....

This is my custom request class:

```
public class MyCustomRequest<T> extends Request<T>{

    private static final String KEY_PICTURE = "file";
    private static final String TAG = "MutlipartRequest";

    private HttpEntity mHttpEntity;
    private final Class mClass;
    private Response.Listener<T>mListener;
    private Map mHeaders;
    private Class<T> clazz;
    private final Gson gson;

    public MyCustomRequest(String url, File file,
                       Class clazz,
                       Map headers,
                       Response.Listener listener,
                       Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        mHeaders = headers;
        mClass = clazz;
        mListener = listener;
        gson = new Gson();
        mHttpEntity = buildMultipartEntity(file);
    }

private HttpEntity buildMultipartEntity(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    return buildMultipartEntity(file);
}

private HttpEntity buildMultipartEntity(File file) {
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    String fileName = file.getName();
    builder.addBinaryBody(KEY_PICTURE, file, ContentType.create("image/*"), fileName);
    return builder.build();
}

@Override
public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return mHeaders != null ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return mHttpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        mHttpEntity.writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String json;
    try {
        json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Encoding problem parsing API response. NetworkResponse:%s", response.toString()), e);
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
    try {
        return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, mClass), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Couldn't API parse JSON response. NetworkResponse:%s", response.toString()), e);
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Couldn't API parse JSON response. Json dump: %s", json));
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

     @Override
     protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
       mListener.onResponse(response);
     }
}
```

And this is the method I use to upload Images from my Activity:

```
  private void uploadImage( String id ){

    String photoUploadUrl = "https://merchantconsole.autogard.io/carservice/api/repair-requests/" + id + "/photos/upload";

    if (_photoPath.length() == 0){
        closeProgress();
    }

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isPart", false)){
        photoUploadUrl = "https://merchantconsole.autogard.io/carservice/api/repair-requests/" + id + "/photos/upload";
    }

    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String , String>();
    String token  = Preference.getInstance().getValue(SubmitActivity.this, PreConst.PREFKEY_TOKEN, "");
    String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    Log.d("token==========>", token);
    headers.put("Content-Type",  "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
    headers.put(ReqConst.PRAM_AUTHENTICATION, token);

   try {
        File file = new File(_photoPath);

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("id", "notuseful");
        // params.put(ReqConst.PARAM_IMAGE_TYPE, String.valueOf(0));
        // String url = ReqConst.SERVER_URL + ReqConst.REQ_UPLOADIMAGE;

        Log.d("photoUploadUrl=====>", photoUploadUrl);


        MultiPartRequest reqMultiPart = new MultiPartRequest(photoUploadUrl, headers, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                closeProgress();

                Log.d("error====>", error.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String json) {
                gotoDashboardActivity();


                Log.d("response============>", json);
            }
        }, file, ReqConst.PRAM_FILE, params);

        reqMultiPart.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                Constants.VOLLEY_TIME_OUT, 0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        AutogardApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(reqMultiPart, photoUploadUrl);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        closeProgress();
    }
```